# How to solve the problem in Visual Studio on Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, timezone

How to solve the problem in Visual Studio on Mac "Could not find file '/usr/share/zoneinfo/North Asia Standard Time", please?!

Comment: Hi.  There are not enough details in your question to help.  At minimum, we would need to see the code that produces this error, or if unrelated to code we'd need steps to reproduce the error.  It sounds like you're somehow using a Windows time zone ID against the Mac OS infrastructure, but it's hard to tell *why* or *how* without more details.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help center.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution for this issue...???